# SqlDelight ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE throws near "ON": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, kmm, sqldelight

I'm using SqlDelight in a KMM project. I'm having problems when using the `INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` command.

After some investigation, I found that I needed to update my dialect version of SqlDelight to 3.25 which I did and it works fine, except it still crashes on Api 29 and below.

I tested it on a pixel 4 Api 29 emulator and on a physical device pixel 3 Api 28 which both crash.

On Pixel 2 Api 30 and above emulators works fine.

SqlDelight version: 1.5.3

dialect = "sqlite:3.25"

My insert statement looks like this

```
insertLocalPortfolioItem:
INSERT INTO localPortfolioList(name, symbol, pricePerShare, currency, cost, noOfShares, logo, availableFunds, orderAction)
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT(symbol) DO UPDATE SET noOfShares=excluded.noOfShares;
```

StackTrace:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ON": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO localPortfolioList(name, symbol, pricePerShare, currency, cost, noOfShares, logo, availableFunds, orderAction)
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT(symbol) DO UPDATE SET noOfShares=excluded.noOfShares
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: You have more chances getting an answer in [kotlin slack](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C0A974TJ9/p1650217795771239), #squarelibraries channel, but to me it looks like a bug and should be [reported](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/new/choose). Also check out if you can reproduce it with the latest alpha **2.0.0-alpha02**, as it may be already fixed there

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be in the version of SQLite shipped with Android, upsert clauses appear in SQLite 3.24+.
If you are using the `SupportSQLiteDatabase` APIs from AndroidX, you can use the SQLite build from Requery, which is a drop-in replacement:

https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android